# Partial upgrade to 15.04 followed by failing to start

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade, 15.04

I have a Lenovo B590, I wanted to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04LTS to Ubuntu 15.04. Two times upgrading stopped (last time stayed 2 hours without showing any evolution in the terminal). I forced the shut down (10sec on the button). Afterstarting it again it opens only until the list below.

-Ubuntu
-Advanced options for Ubuntu Memory test (memtest86+)
-Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
-Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sda1)
-Advanced options for Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sda1)
I know it usualy carries on until showing the desktop, but now it just stops at this point. 
What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: And how exactly are you trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04? You first need to upgrade to 14.10.

Comment: Failed upgrades are difficult to fix, partial upgrades are worse. I highly suggest a fresh inatall

Comment: I entered Advanced Options --> Recovery mode... somehow it started and it shows that 15.04 version is running now. However I run the Software Updater and ... let him do his job. :D